# Cheapest way to get from Athens to Hydra by ferry

Tags: budget, ferries, greece, islands

I will be visiting Athens, and I'd love to visit some of the islands. Hydra looks really nice and special and I'd like to spend a day in the village and the nature there.

However, the only transportation I can find from Athens is a 51 Euro round trip ticket, which seems quite expensive.

Does anyone know a cheaper way with the ferry? For example, is there a slower, old school, ferry?

Comment: Are you willing to swim? If not, what are your requirements, other than 'cheapest'? Are you looking specifically for the cheapest public ferry?

Comment: @Flimzy yes, the cheapest ferry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hellenic Seaways are using flying dolphins that's why tickets are expensive. I could not find any route with a "traditional" ferry from Piraeus to Hydra.

Your only alternative would be a coach [Athens to Galatas](http://www.ktel-argolidas.gr/?module=default&pages_id=56&lang=en) (return) costs 25 Euros (175 kilometers - 2 hours and 30 minutes). [Galatas to Metochi](http://www.hydralines.gr/index_en.html) is 30 minutes away (not sure how you'd get there) and then Metochi to Hydra is either [6.5 Euros](http://www.hydra.com.gr/car-transport/) or [8 Euros](http://hydraspetses.com/index.php/kaiki-boat-trip-hydra), by boat. Some more timetables [here](http://www.hydra.gr/en/gettinghere/dromologia-metoxi-hydra.php).